# Recent changes with Firebase Authentication via. Google Sign-In?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I've a question to people who use Firebase Google Sign-In authentication:

My app, which has already been working for a couple of months, is using both Google Sign-In and e-mail/password options for Firebase Authentication. However about a week ago I've noticed that the Google Sign-In stopped working. No code was changed, also the e-mail/password option works just as usual.

I've checked the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), it's still the same (My app copies the authentication method from the documentation).

Did you face a similar problem too? If yes, please tell me how can I solve it.

Here is my code related to Google Sign-in inside my LoginActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...   
    //--------Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Connection failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    mGoogleBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SignIn();
        }
    });

}

private void SignIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mProgress.setMessage("Signing in with Google Account...");
    mProgress.show();
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // ...
            mProgress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Google sign in failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    checkUserExist();

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void checkUserExist() {
    final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            } else {
                Intent setupIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(setupIntent);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Here are my app and project level build.gradle files: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c9737e898ca2568129af63e61a30f16

Comment: I've had a similar issue but outside of android. When my sign-in code runs it pops a window that immediately closes itself. It used to ask if the account was allowed to be used.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem and its solution? I am facing the same in iOS.

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal Unfortunately not.

Comment: Can you share your gradle file as well?

Comment: @sam_c I've edited my question and added link to gradle files code

Comment: I've had issues with Google Auth in the past but not of this nature. Without being able to personally debug I'm afraid I can't say. Without stepping through the only thing I can think of is that your firebase and play services auth versions are pretty dated and you might want to try bumping them to 11.4.0 respectively. Otherwise if you haven't set break points and debugged (I suspect you have though) then I would try that. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: @sam_c Yeah, I'll do the update the dependencies versions, but the main problem is that everything worked previously and then, all of a sudden the sign-in started to fail in the very same app. Thanks anyway, I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: When you say Google Sign-In stopped working, what happens when you try to sign in with Google? Does the Firebase console show users previously authenticated through Google?

Comment: @JenPerson No, I just get the "Google sign in failed!" message from the onActivityResult() method, which is triggered by the Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data); returning not successful.

Comment: According to the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInResult.html#public-methodsyou can run `result.getStatusCode()`, and then check the status code to determine the cause. Also, while an unlikely cause, have you checked to make sure that Google Sign In is toggled on in the Firebase console?

Comment: @JenPerson I just (literally seconds ago) found a solution, I'm writing it down. No, it's not the toggle on Firebase, it's about that god damn SHA-1 certificate. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @SerjArdovic I was able to solve it. Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256349/google-sign-in-is-redirecting-to-google-chrome-not-returning-to-my-app/44305293?noredirect=1#comment75617354_44305293

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal Great, but that's not the same problem I had. I've also solved the issue just yesterday. Below; I've written the answer, though there are still some things unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'll admit one thing - it had nothing to do with the code... I managed to fix the issue, and I'll explain how.

I debugged the app with the debugger as I was recommended by good people inside the comments and it turned out that inside the onActivityResult() method the Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data) was returning this error result code:

> Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}

This was more than enough to understand where to dig. I looked up into my Firebase console -> Project -> Project settings -> SHA-1 fingerprints.

What is interesting - there was a fingerprint there, the one I've put before. Anyways, I decided to check if it's the same with the one I get from Android Studio -> Gradle Projects -> inside the project/app/tasks/android/ folder there is a signingReport which contains SHA-1. To my surprise, the SHA-1 fingerprints did not match. Anyways, I copied it from the AS and added 2nd line inside Firebase Console. Guess what? It works now...

I still have a lot of questions about why this could happened, since it did happen all of a sudden as I explained previously in my question.

I hope this info will help others who had a similar issue. Nevertheless, question solved, but since there is a bounty set **I'll award it to the person, who'll explain me this magic...**

Comment: So this couldn't be due to SHA-1 mismatch of release APK and debug APK for the app have already been working for a couple of months.

Comment: That's exactly what I do not understand. How is this even possible? I did not anyhow update the app on the device, it just stopped signing in all of a sudden. Also, now I have 2 SHA-1 certificates in my Firebase console... So confusing.

Comment: Have you migratd to different machine? If you move to a new developer machine the debug keystore is likely different, you need to put that keystore SHA1 fingerprint too.

Comment: Well I haven't thought about that. Actually yes, I got myself a new macbook earlier this year. Do you think this is the reason of such misbehaviour? But does this mean that every computer I work on will generate a new SHA-1 and I'll need to put them all on Firebase?

Comment: Of course, unless you use the same keystore file to build your app. This is because the SHA-1 fingerprint is generated by the keystore used to sign the builds and the default debug keystore(SDK generates automatically) located in the android home directory is different on every computer. So you should either add the fingerprints from all the the debug keystores(different on every development devices) or use the same keystore file for every build. To know more about signing your app, [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, I didn't know that. I guess I'll have to get more information on this topic from the docs link you've provided.

Comment: Hope, this was the mystery behind the problem. You can be sure if you know the time you changed the device and had your first built there. Those information shall also help you a lot regarding debug keystore, release keystore and their expiry too, meanwhile I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, make sure to provide good info and up the question, so that other people who have the same problem find it easily. I believe there is a serious lack of information available on this topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155072/discussion-between-journey-and-serj-ardovic).

Comment: Sir, I've a few questions. Firstly, did you find the cause? And, another, I wonder how could email sign in method of the same project kept on working while the google sign in failed? After all SHA key for the whole project was mismatched at last ! Either you must be missing something or it must be the Google's technical fault.

Answer (score 3):

As OP has found the solution to the problem and answered it already. I'll be trying to explain the cases, as requested by OP, that might be the real causes behind the problem. Before that lets know something about `keystores` and `certificates`.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#overview) says:

> Android requires that all APKs be digitally signed with a **public-key certificate** before they can be installed. Even that application you build and run during the development period must be signed with a certificate. If you don't do it manually Android Studio automatically signs your APK with a debug certificate generated by the Android SDK tools. The first time you run or debug your project in Android Studio, the IDE automatically creates the debug keystore and certificate in `$HOME/.android/debug.keystore`, and sets the keystore and key passwords.  A public-key certificate, also known as a digital certificate or an identity certificate, contains the public key of a public/private key pair, as well as some other metadata identifying the owner of the key (for example, name and location). The owner of the certificate holds the corresponding private key.
>
> When you sign an APK, the signing tool attaches the public-key certificate to the APK. The public-key certificate serves as as a "fingerprint" that uniquely associates the APK to you and your corresponding private key. This helps Android ensure that any future updates to your APK are authentic and come from the original author.
>
> A **keystore** is a binary file that contains one or more private keys.
>
> Every app must use the same certificate throughout its lifespan in order for users to be able to install new versions as updates to the app.

Back to the question; after studying the OP's problem and with a short conversation with him I came up with following deduction:

- **He must be using one keystore/certificate for development and different certificate for Project Setting(firebase console).**
- **Since, Google Sign-In was working fine for a couple of months but stopped lately, he must have changed the keystore lately.**
- **Found that he has just migrated to new development device and hence the app he build now might have a new debug keystore file and new certificate which shall be, in fact, different from that in Project Setting.**

The case is still a mystery, I later knew that the OP never built or ran his app from the new device.

> **P.S.** Android Studio automatically creates the debug keystore and certificate in $HOME/.android/debug.keystore, and sets the keystore and key passwords the first time you run or debug your project. This mean that every computer you work on will generate a new SHA-1 unless you have a copy of a previous keystore file and you use it.

Answer (score -1):

This might be the case -

- In your device, you have added just one email account which is not authorized in your app. Other than this, there is no other account added in your device.
- So when you click on your 'Sign in with Google' button, it automatically takes that email account. But it is not authorized so it fails.

Solution -
Add your authorized account in your device. Now when you click on 'Sign in with Gooogle', it will show a pop up and ask you which account you want to choose. Select the correct one and you must be able to login. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: No, this is not the case.