# Firebase google authentication not working in release mode

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am building an app in the android studio using firebase authentication...how do I google login in release mode? It works in debug mode but not in release mode.

Comment: Are you sure added your SHA key in firebase project?

Comment: I had a similar issue. Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41419942/recent-changes-with-firebase-authentication-via-google-sign-in

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468529/cannot-authenticate-with-google-on-a-real-device-when-accesing-the-app-from-play).

Comment: check your `google-services.json` file in your project, and see if the SHA signatures `certificate_hash` available there matches with your release key SHA.

Comment: yes my SHA1 IS there

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue. And it resolve by:

- Go to google play console
- In **Release management** -> **App signing**
- Get SHA-1 in **App signing certificate**
- Update your SHA-1 in console firebase
- Download new file google-services.json
- Update file google-services.json in your app
- Create new release

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot :)