# firebase phone authentication in react native app not working after release

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, authentication

i made react native app with firebase phone authentication.
The authentication work perfect on emulator (ios and android) and on real device emulator.
But when I create the apk file and install it on my phone, while I click on 'login' that is no response from the app and I can't login.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: i have encountered the some problem follow  following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439480/firebase-google-authentication-not-working-in-release-mode

Comment: I already tried it. I got new SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys and updated my firebase. Then I downloaded google-services.json file, and make a build in app center, I downloaded the apk and still not working,

Comment: ok, I solved it, I just took the SHA-1 debug key instead SHA-1 release key. thanks!